# trouble setting values to a collection in an abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm working with reflection on an abstract class, and running into an issue where I'm unable to use the PropertyInfo.SetValue method to assign values to an existing List object.

Here are some (very) shortened class declarations.

```
public abstract class User { }
public class Subscriber : User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> AttributeList { get; set; }
}
```

Now inside of User, I have a method that extracts data from an XML with an unknown number of elements. I parse through these elements, and if they are recognized as a property of User (or any of its children), I populate the property.

```
private void ExtractElement(XElement inner)
{
    // Uses reflection to get the correct Derived class (Initiate, Member, Subscriber)
    Type tUser = this.GetType();

    var prop = tUser.GetProperty("AttributeList"); // hard-coded for brevity
    object value = "Random Value" // same

    var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType);
    if (nullableType == null)
        nullableType = prop.PropertyType;


    if (nullableType == typeof(int))
    {
        prop.SetValue(this, int.Parse(value as string), null);
    }
    else if (nullableType == typeof(List<string>))
    {
        var myList = (List<string>)(prop.GetValue(this, null));
        myList.Add(value as string);
        prop.SetValue(this, myList, null); // <- This doesn't save changes.
    }
    else
    {
        prop.SetValue(this, value as string, null);
    }
```

When it drops into this last section, myList is populated correctly. But when I attempt to set the value of AttributeList to myList, the changes don't 'stick'. Judging from other posts about reflection, my best guess is that I am pulling a copy of AttributeList (because of boxing/unboxing?), and affecting that instead of the original. Is there a way to directly affect the original in this type of situation? Why doesn't the last line of my code throw an error if the changes aren't saved?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not just call `Add` via reflection on `prop.GetValue(this, null)`? I have used reflection for a similar task and calling `Add` reflectively worked fine.

Comment: I just wrote some code to test this out and it seems to work fine (class that inherits abstract class, abstract class gets its own derived property and does whatever you are doing here). I believe you need to supply some more information here.

Comment: Yeah, there is something very strange going on with my class. On the first pass, this seems to work fine. On additional passes, the list value does not change. I'm going to look into this a little deeper and update my question.

Comment: You're effectively calling `myList =  (this as Subscriber).AttributeList; myList.Add(value as string); (this as Subscriber).AttributeList = myList;` That last statement is of no value. AttributeList is already set to myList.

Comment: Related to my last comment, before and after are the same thing. They are not 2 distinct entities. They are the same entity.

Comment: There is no boxing/unboxing. Boxing and unboxing happen with value types, not reference types.

Comment: Pete is right; change your code to `var before = new List<string>((List<string>)prop.GetValue(this, null));`  Then you'll have a copy of the list in `before` and the actual list in `after`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for all of your input, guys. My issue was caused because that ExtractElement method up there was being called in the constructor of the abstract class... which was being called before the constructor of the derived class, where the AttributeList was overridden. Argh. @MohammedHossain  Your answer did help clean up my code a lot, so I'll mark yours as the answer if you want to add it below.

Comment: Thanks @Pete too for re-educating me about values vs. references. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:

```
if (nullableType == typeof(List<string>))
{
    ((List<string>)(prop.GetValue(this, null))).Add(value as string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. That one line beat my 3 lines of redundant code any day.